# Direction of acceleration in case of Newton’s 3rd law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, free-body-diagram

[image]

If S  pushes L with a force of 540N and L pushes (By3rd law) with a force of 540N.Then Will their direction of acceleration be opposite to direction of force ?

Comment: No. S would be accelerated to the left and L to the right. The real case of persons pushing each others is different because we aren't billiard balls, but no one get accelerated in a direction opposite to the force actin on him/her.

Comment: Force of S in right direction but it’s acc in left direction.

Comment: see my comment to your other question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your pictures are clear enough but let's say *S pushes L to the right* with some force , so by *Newton's third law*, **L also pushes S by the same force in opposite direction i.e. to the left**.

And the direction of force decides the direction of their acceleration. So the acceleration of S is towards the left and that of L is towards the right.

Hope it helps .

Comment: Force of L coincides with direction of S right.

Comment: You mean to say that reaction force by L due to S in left direction.Therefore acceleration of S is in left direction right

Comment: Ok.Thank you . . .

Comment: Yes.That was my question.I got confused with their force direction but now fine.

Comment: @robert patrick one more thing that direction of force decides the direction of acceleration . The force of S **on L**was in right but **it experienced the same force from L to left** and hence accelerated to left..